# Jquery Monday - Sunday hourly sceduler for opening hours

Tags: jquery, plugins, time

**EDIT:**

Found this which sort of answers my question so this was pointless: codepen.io/NaszvadiG/pen/miGaJ

---

Trying to find something existing to save time but spent a while looking now so thought I would ask in case I am just looking for the wrong thing.

Basically looking for something in jQuery that I can use for picking opening hours for a business, my idea is to implement something like the utorrent scheduler feature where there is a list of days Sunday - Monday and each day has 24 boxes to the right of it and you can click on a box to mark it as closed/open on that hour.

Has anyone come across something like this before?

See below for the utorrent scheduler, I would only need 2 opens closed/open, on/off type thing.

[image: Utorrent Scheduler]

Answer (score 0):

While searching the same problem, I found this solution.
Maybe that answers your needs
http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#display-grid

Comment: Thank you, never seen this :D

Comment: I did use this idea but I did something different in the end because my original idea was a bit over the top for what my client really needed. I will leave what I ended up with here: http://uk-sam.com/jquizzle/open-hours.html   it uses standard jQuery and Ui using Selectable and a simple time picker plugin.